# Max and min of $f(x,y)=(x)^{2x}+(2y)^{y}$

Tags: real-analysis

The domain of f is $\{(x,y)\in R^2: x>0,y>0\}$.
f isn't limited up.With the Hessian method i have founded a local min in $(\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{2e})$.It's a global min?

Comment: sure, one sufficient condition for global min is convexity at every point. here the hessian is positive definite for every point in the domain

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x\ln{x}$.

Thus, $f'(x)=\ln{x}+1$, which says that $x_{min}=\frac{1}{e}.$.

Id est, $$x^x\geq\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}$$ and we see that our function get's a minimal  value in the point $\left(\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{2e}\right)$ because
$$f(x,y)=(x^x)^{2}+\left((2y)^{2y}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$